# Do we need to update project (the blue button on upper right) everytime make changes in intelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I made some changes in my codes to solve the problem of inconsistent result and the final resuts still showing different before I updating the project, but after updating the project, seems like my problem solved and the new code worked. I didn't change anything else the only different is I updated my code, I'm new to Java and a bit confused, can someone explain? Many thanks.

Comment: in intelliJ you have to recompile class if you are making changes while debugging to see effects

Comment: Hi I think I have found the issue, I changed the setting of 'parallelism' in Flink execution and I can recreate the issue again which means there's something going on for 'parallelism'